# how to assemble a map that has a list inside

Tags: apex

I need to use this code:

```
List<Asset> assets = map.get(accountId);
```

For this, I created this map:

```
Map<Id, List<Asset>>
```

but I do not know how to assemble this map, I have a list of the Assets, and each Asset has a lookup of the Account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to iterate over the list, and then add items to the map.

There are a couple of ways to go about that, but the generally accepted "best practice" is as follows:

```java
// First, you need to declare and initialize the map
Map<Id, List<Asset>> accountIdToAssets = new Map<Id, List<Asset>>();

// Loop over assets
for(Asset ast :assetList){
    // Check to see if we've encountered this AccountId before
    if(!accountIdToAssets.containsKey(ast.AccountId)){
        // If we haven't, then we should put a new list into the map
        //   so that we can use it later
        accountIdToAssets.put(ast.AccountId, new List<Asset>());
    }

    // At this point, we're guaranteed to have something in the map we can work with
    // Non-primitive types (like our List<Asset>) are stored in the map by
    //   reference
    // That means that map.get(accountId) returns a list
    // We're then calling .add() on that list
    accountIdToAssets.get(ast.AccountId).add(ast);
}
```

By not adding the asset to the list when we first create the list, we make it so that we can simply `.add()` it to the list regardless of whether it's the first item or the Nth item. This approach allows us to omit the ELSE, and saves us a little bit of typing.